# AWS Elastic Beanstalk update environment error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I stuck with strange error.

Command:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name my-env --version-label c4fc4991b8838933de0f498e2e0060b522078092
```

A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the UpdateEnvironment operation: The bucket name parameter must be specified when requesting an object

Also I could not find any bucket related configuration on [this site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-environment.html).

This is my policy

```
    {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetBucketPolicy"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*"
  ]
},
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
    "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
    "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
    "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
    "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
    "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
    "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
    "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
    "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
    "ec2:DescribeImages",
    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
    "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
    "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
    "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationOptions",
    "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationSettings",
    "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentResources",
    "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments",
    "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
    "elasticbeanstalk:RequestEnvironmentInfo",
    "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo",
    "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
    "elasticbeanstalk:ValidateConfigurationSettings",
    "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeInstanceHealth",
    "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
    "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
    "rds:DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions",
    "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
    "sns:CreateTopic",
    "sns:GetTopicAttributes",
    "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Comment: What's the result of `aws describe-application-versions --version-label yourversion`?

Comment: Have you upgraded awscli?  Mine was working at 1.7.42, and started seeing your error after 1.8.9   which version are you on?

Comment: i'm using 1.8.8 maybe it could be version issue. But i fixed this one.

Comment: It's not a version issue, I am getting it in even AWS Console UI as well as CLI (aws-cli/1.11.13 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.4.0-1043-aws botocore/1.4.70)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've spoken to customer support guy from AWS who confirmed that it is a policy issue. So I changed my first statement like this below. I've added the value `"s3:Get*"` end of the Action array.

```
        {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:Get*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: This fixed my issue on Codeship Elastic Beanstalk deployment. Just wanted to mention that so other's googling for this error with their Codeship setup will find it. Thanks Tengis for the solution.

Comment: @Tengis: did you use the AWS forum to get suport? If so, can you please share the thread? I'd be curious to have some explanation about this.

Comment: @Antoine Ah no mate. I spoken to via private chat with AWS customer support.